# MySQL: LEFT JOIN table ON table.id IN ()

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

**Orders**

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | notes |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | Adam |   1,2 |
|  2 | Ema  |     3 |
|  3 | Petr |   1,3 |
+----+------+-------+
```

**Notes**

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | text                |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | This is first note  |
|  2 | This is second note |
|  3 | And third note      |
+----+---------------------+
```

I need to to select row from Orders and group concat Text from second table based on Orders.notes.

If I use this statement

```
SELECT o.name, o.notes
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT n.text SEPARATOR ';') AS notes_text
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN notes n ON n.id IN (1,2)
WHERE o.id = 1;
```

Result is as expected `This is first note;This is second note`

But if I use this statement that I need, where notes.id IN (orders.notes)

```
SELECT o.name, o.notes
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT n.text SEPARATOR ';') AS notes_text
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN notes n ON n.id IN (o.notes)
WHERE o.id = 1
```

It only returns first text `This is first note`. Why?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab90d/5)

Comment: You just asking `why` or you need another desired result?

Comment: I need to use second statement but expect result like in first one.

Comment: `orders.notes` is a non-scalable solution to this problem. You should instead put an `order_id` into your `notes` table, then the SQL will make so much more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL dbs will **NOT** "tear apart" a csv value in a field. These three fragments will parse/execute identically:

```
... n.id IN (o.notes)
... n.id IN ('1,2')
... n.id = '1,2'
```

Note the quotes. the `1,2` is treated as a monolithic string, not as two separate values spearated by a comma.

If you want to use this bad table design (you REALLY should normalize), then use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead.

Note that this will chain  you to MySQL, and you lose portability.

Comment: I know it's bad design and understand that it is a string but it is confusing that the second statement returns first note.

Comment: Anyway FIND_IN_SET() solve this. Thanks

Comment: the `in ('1,2')` works because you're doing a numeric-string comparison, so mysql converts your `1,2` string into a number, which becomes simply `1`.